# Synchronized return objective-c

Tags: objective-c, synchronized

```
- (id)methodThatReturnsSomething
{
    @synchronized(self) {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

When I do this on Xcode, it returns me a warning: "Control reaches end of non-void function"

Is there any problem with that code?

Answer (score 11):

It barfs up a compiler warning because of a bug in some versions of the compiler that are fixed in other / later versions of the compiler.

In this case, yes, you really did stumble upon a compiler bug.

Answer (score 1):

The synchronization in the code as posted is redundant but there is no problem with it as such:
`@synchronized` blocks are either exited normally or through exceptions. As you already have a `return` statement in it, another statement after the block is not needed.

Comment: The code, as posted, is perfectly meaningful.  It just causes an unnecessary lock to be taken.

Comment: @bbum: True, thats what i meant to say.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you want to do in your code, but

```
- (id)methodThatReturnsSomething
{
    @synchronized(self) {
    }
    return nil;
}
```

should have the same effect (postponing the return until the lock associated to `self` is freed), without the compiler warning.

But: what did you want to do? You don't have to put a `@synchronized` in this manner.

Comment: This synchronized stands the risk of being completely removed by the optimizer, which of course shouldn't make any difference anyhow - like you say, "what did problem did you want to solve"?